# Google Cloud Console - Add authorized redirect urls for authentication

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

Error I get with google firebase authentication
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KyRQ.png

Click the link to see the error I get. My issue is that I am told I need to allow the redirect URL.

I have searched countless tutorials, but none are helping. I am aware it has to do with Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://support.hmhco.com/s/article/Authorization-Error-Error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-Google-Single-Sign-On) should provide you with the solution to your problem. You'll probably need to adapt what it says to your context, since this primarily applies to the web-app ThinkCentral they're promoting - but it should be enough to get you to where you want to be.

1. Get the URL redirect URL you're trying to add
2. Go to [Google console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
3. Navigate to APIs & Services (image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2PIB.png))
   [image: Console - API & Services menu]
4. Click on Credentials
5. Now edit the existing OAuth web application (image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjKI7.png)) (I presume you'll have one, since you wouldn't be getting that error, you'd be seeing a different one) - if you have more than one, make sure you're going to edit the right one.
   [image: Console - editing OAuth Web Application]
6. On the edit screen (image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE4qB.png)), Add URI, shown beneath Authorized redirect URIs - its near the bottom, after the JavaScript section; you might have to scroll down. Paste in the Client Redirect URL that you're trying to use.
7. Remember to save!

[image: Console - Adding Authorized Redirect URIs]

Image links shamelessly taken from the documentation link above